# ADB doesn't recognize Samsung Gear Live or LG G watch

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

I am trying to execute `adb` on the Samsung Gear Live watch on Windows 7. I don't seem to find device drivers to get it recognized by ADB. This is what I already have -

1. I have enabled ADB debugging in Gear Live already
2. I went to device manager and pointed the device driver location for gear live to `sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`
3. No luck. `adb devices` yields no results.
4. I don't seem to find the device driver elsewhere for Windows 7.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm running Windows 8.1 and this method worked perfectly fine:

Open your device manager and select "Update Driver Software..." on your Gear Live:
[image: Device Manager]

Select "Browse My Computer for driver software":
[image: browse]

Select "Let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer":
[image: manually pick]

Select "Android Device". If not available, it may have been renamed to "Samsung Android Device", "Asus Android Device", and so on.
[image: pick Android Device]

Then, choose the "Android Composite ADB interface" from Google, Samsung or in fact almost any other Android devices vendor:
[image: pick Composite ADB interface]

This works because usually, the only differences between all these composite ADB Windows drivers are the usb_id and the signature.

Now adb devices should return your device and a popup will appear on your *Android device*, to authorize your computer.

Comment: Strange, this method does not work with Windows 7 64-bit. Or at least it didn't. I'll recheck.

Comment: If your device shows up as a "Android ADB Interface" (not composite), uninstall the associated driver and plug your device again.

Comment: ok, so here is a deal. Long story short - your solution worked! I didn't see 'Android Device', but I saw 'Samsung Android Phone'. I selected that and moved on. Second change is I didn't see 'Android Composite ADB Interface' but saw 'Android ADB Interface'. So, I hit cancel and went back to device manager, uninstalled associated device driver and restarted machine as requested by machine. Restarted steps and now I could see 'Android Composite ADB Interface', selected it and it worked! Thanks ph0b!

Comment: Works perfectly on Windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: his solution didn't work for me. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and have LG G Watch connected via USB, and it is showing up under "Other devices," but neither "Android Device" nor any LG-related option is showing up under the "Common hardware types." Does anyone know any other workarounds?

Comment: Have you any adb driver installed on your computer ? You can install the one from Google from the SDK download manager. If it doesn't show up you can pick "all compatible devices" to select it.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 7 64-bit. I already had some adb drivers installed for HTC One S and Nexus 7.

Comment: How about a Mac with Maverick? Doesn't work for me :(

Comment: On the last window I don't see "Google Inc." manufacturer. Only Samsung & HTC

Comment: If you've downloaded Google USB drivers from the SDK Download manager, and installed them from ..\extras\google\usb_driver, you should get it. Otherwise that's not an issue, Samsung composite ADB driver will work fine.

Answer (score 12):

On Win 7, the way I found is to make a copy of "...\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver" on desktop or elsewhere, then edit file "android_winusb.inf" to add Gear Live description :

- First open Device Manager and right click "Gear Live" in "Other devices" and choose Properties. In "Details" folder, choose "material identification numbers" and copy the second one (My os is in french, so i try to translate names correctly...). The number to copy must look like (or be): "USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002"
- Then edit "android_winusb.inf" (the one in the folder previously copied, in case of...) and add under "[Google.NTx86]", at the end, these lines :

  ;Gear Live

  %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002

  %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002&MI_01

Be careful to change "USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002" with your material number if needed (but let "&MI_01" on second line.

- Make the same under [Google.NTamd64].
- Now you can go back to "device manager", right click on "Gear Live", choose "Update driver software" then "Browse my computer..." and choose the folder where you just edit "android_winusb.inf".

Comment: So it turns out this was the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738242/android-wear-lg-g-watch-usb-driver-doesnt-update-on-windows-7?noredirect=1#comment38379451_24738242 In fact, I should have remembered this because I had to do something very similar for Glass when it first came out! Cheers mate.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. "material identification numbers" is "Hardware Ids" in English version

Comment: "I'm getting the error "the has for the file is not present in the specified catalog"  Any ideas?  http://imgur.com/cqzeRoo

Answer (score 0):

You need to be paired to a phone and it will pop up a messaged to approve your computer to connect to adb just like connecting a phone regularly.