# Android Wear LG G Watch USB Driver doesn't update on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, usb, wear-os

I have followed the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24607317/624869

But wasn't able to update my driver. I get the following error in Windows:

[image]

I am on Windows 7. My Nexus 5 is recognized just fine by ADB. Also my SDK is updated completely, all the way to Android 4.4W.

What's going on here?

Comment: You have to get drivers from sdk/extras/google/driver as for N5.

Comment: Can you elaborate? As in the link I posted I included that extras/google/usb_driver directory and said to include all subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer to my question was given by this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716409/624869

I'll copy and paste in case it gets deleted:

On Win 7, the way I found is to make a copy of "...\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver" on desktop or elsewhere, then edit file "android_winusb.inf" to add Gear Live description :

First open Device Manager and right click "Gear Live" in "Other devices" and choose Properties. In "Details" folder, choose "material identification numbers" and copy the second one (My os is in french, so i try to translate names correctly...). The number to copy must look like (or be): "USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002"

Then edit "android_winusb.inf" (the one in the folder previously copied, in case of...) and add under "[Google.NTx86]", at the end, these lines :

```
;Gear Live

%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002

%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002&MI_01
```

Be careful to change "USB\VID_18D1&PID_D002" with your material number if needed (but let "&MI_01" on second line.

Make the same under [Google.NTamd64].

Now you can go back to "device manager", right click on "Gear Live", choose "Update driver software" then "Browse my computer..." and choose the folder where you just edit "android_winusb.inf".

Turns out about a year ago I had to do something very similar for Google Glass (which, as you'll see, should now be in that usb_driver file by default). Should have remembered. Or rather, Google should see this stuff coming =)

Answer (score 0):

The above did not work for me so I find another answer [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/g-watch/help/how-to-fix-driver-problems-t2809673)

So the long story, short:

**Method 1:**

Download the Google USB drivers from here

Extract the ZIP anywhere

In the Windows Device Manager right click "G Watch" and select to update the drivers

Select search for drivers on the computer (2nd option)

Point Windows to that folder you just extracted (should be called "usb_driver")

Select that folder and Windows should install the correct drivers. You might have to restart the PC.

If method 1 fails (which was the case for me) go to method 2

**Method 2:**

Again in the Windows Device Manager right click "G Watch" and select to update the drivers

Select search for drivers on the computer (2nd option)

Select choose driver from a list of device drivers on this computer

Choose "Android Device" and click next

Select "Google" as manufacturer and "Android ADB Interface Version X.x.x.x" (newest one, for me it is 9.0.0.0) as model then click next

Select yes in the next dialogue

Windows should now manually install this driver