# Transferring large application to Android Wear through Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, testing, wear-os, large-files

I am developing a large application for Android Wear through Android Studio (~200 MB). Trying to test the application on my LG G Watch R through "Debugging over Bluetooth" is taking a lot of time to send the large app to the Watch.

Are there any alternatives / faster methods to send the application to the Watch for testing?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I have fixed the issue thanks to [ianhanniballake's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) advice. It turns out that my USB Driver was not correctly installed on my PC. Anyone with a similar issue should reinstall their Google USB Driver by following this [Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583354/adb-doesnt-recognize-samsung-gear-live-or-lg-g-watch).

Thank you again.

Comment: The Google Play Store currently limits the APK size to 50MB for all apps - since Wear apps are packaged into the main APK, you'll also be limited by that if you are distributing on the Google Play Store.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am not releasing the application to the PlayStore. I am just using it for testing purposes. As a result, there is no 50 MB limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dock that comes with the LG G Watch R can also be plugged into the computer, allowing you to use the much faster USB connection to install your Wear app.